# NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: -67068 in sandbox related item

Tags: objective-c, macos, runtime-error, sandbox

NSFileSandboxingRequestRelatedItemExtension: an error was received from pboxd instead of a token. Domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: -67068

This appear when I was playing with sandbox related item. I have tried the code in individial project. It works. But in my main project, it not works.

What is this meaning? Anyone know how to solve? Thanks.

Comment: This is a code signing error: errSecCSStaticCodeNotFound = -67068, /* cannot find code object on disk */ Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks~ what is its meaning?  /* cannot find code object on disk */ ? Is it some project setting problem?